# GCC array default fill value

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, embedded

**Question in a nutshell**

I recently discovered an extension to gcc which I have found very cool and helpful. This allows you to specify the index at which initializer elements go in an array. So instead of

```
static const uint8_t array[4] = {
    2,
    1,
    3,
    4
};
```

one can write

```
static const uint8_t array[4] = {
    [1] = 1,
    [0] = 2,
    [2] = 3,
    [3] = 4
};
```

Often, however, I have an array for which I have one or two specific values which need to be different, with the rest of the array set to some default value. I'd like to be able to do this all in an initializer; something like

```
static const uint8_t array[4] = {
    [1]               = 1,
    [everything else] = 0
};
```

Does anyone know of a good way to do this? The only way I've come up with (which seems more than a little hacky) is to define an `EVERYTHING_ELSE` macro which depends on the same values, and the array length -- something like this:

```
#define VALUE                            (8)
#define DEFAULT                          (1)
#define INDEX                            (2)
#define ARRAY_LENGTH                     (4)
#define EVERYTHING_ELSE(n, index, len)   (((index) + (n)) % (len))

static const uint8_t array[ARRAY_LENGTH] = {
    [EVERYTHING_ELSE(1, INDEX, ARRAY_LENGTH)] = DEFAULT,
    [EVERYTHING_ELSE(2, INDEX, ARRAY_LENGTH)] = DEFAULT,
    [EVERYTHING_ELSE(3, INDEX, ARRAY_LENGTH)] = DEFAULT,
    [INDEX]                                   = VALUE;
};
```

**A bit of background**

I do embedded systems programming, which often means configuring peripherals. In this particular case, each element of an array might correspond to a channel in a peripheral. If I'm building a project for different boards, with slightly different pin assignment, I might be using different channels in different cases. To help enforce correctness and portability I prefer to define this value in one place, and write code which depends on this one value.

Additionally, I need to ensure that all other channels in that particular peripheral are deactivated. In the example above, I have a simple array of ints, but generally the case is more complicated (it's an array of initializer structs, or something like that). I know that a static array will be initialized to zero by default, but it's not always the case that zero corresponds to uninitialized; further, I consider it bad form to depend on a library constant being a specific value for correctly functioning code.

I could make the array non-const and do initialization at runtime, but in an embedded system this can be a problem. If you only have 6k of RAM, there's strong motivation to put everything that can be determined at compile-time in flash memory, to leave maximum RAM space for things that actually NEED to vary at runtime.

Comment: Well if you want all but a few values initialized to zero, then why not just initialize it to zero, and then in some initialization routine set the few specific values to what they should be?

Comment: Zero initializing "everything else" is straightforward: `int a[5] = {[2]=5};` and the rest of the elements (except 3rd element) are implicitly set to 0. But to initialize with different value, you have to use some hacks like you have.

Comment: You could use “another” GNU extension: `uint8_t array[4] = { [0 ... 3] = DEFAULT, [1] = 1 };`.

Comment: @cremno Actually what OP has is part of standard C. Only the range initializer you suggest is a gcc extension. Considering he seems to be OK with extensions, your suggestion could be what he wanted.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't want to do that because that would force the array into RAM, in my use case that's not acceptable (see the wall of text at the end)

Comment: @cremno That's exactly what I'm looking for! I knew about that extension, but didn't connect it with the 'last initializer' thing. Thanks!

Comment: @BlueMoon: Yes, however we don't know if he's using C99 or C11. If he's using C90, it's actually an extension.

Comment: @BlueMoon I'm compiling with C99 currently.  In any case, I'm using gcc. Maybe in the future I'll have to worry more about compiler portability, but these days it's not really an issue

Comment: @cremno: Sure it works? You are actually initializing `[1]` twice.

Comment: @Olaf: Yes, I'm sure but any decent compiler will emit a warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a gcc-speciality, but a standard feature since C99, called [*designated initializer*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9p6). It is also possible for struct fields (which is much more relevant to emphasise imo).

Note that the standard only allows to specify a single index (using a *constant expression*), not a range, that is a gcc extension. There is also no standard way to set "all other" fields to a value other than 0 (0.0 for floats/complex, NULL for pointers).

As defined by the standard, fields/elements not explicitly initialized are set to 0. However, if you have a larger array with few fields set to non-0, you should explicitly set these fields from your code (if the object is not `const` of course). Reason is that 0-initialized global objects do not consume ROM/Flash/file-space, while the initializers for non-zero initialitzed objects have to be stored explicitly - completely. For embedded systems, this is apparently not a good idea.

If you have to set up a large array, it might be a good idea to create a C source code file with the array by a small program (I use Python for such, as that is very simple). This file can then be `#include` in your program code (if `static`) or compiled/linked with your pregram as any other source code.